# Docker does not search for a file in a directory

Tags: docker

I created a docker file.

```
FROM node:13.6.0-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /src
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

COPY ./package.json .
COPY ./package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081

CMD npm run start:dev
```

Structure of my project.

```
.
└── my-app
    └── docker-compose.yml
    └── ...
    └── server
        └── docker
            └── Dockerfile
        └── src
            └── ....
        ├── package.json
        ├── package-lock.json
        └── ...
```

When I build the container, I get an error.

> ERROR: Service 'server' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder791989542/package.json: no such file or directory

I understand that my files are in a different directory. I tried to solve my problems like this.

```
COPY ./../package.json .
COPY ./../package-lock.json .
```

But I also got an error

> ERROR: Service 'server' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../package.json ()

How to tell the docker so that he is looking for files not in the docker folder where the dockerfile file is located, but in the src folder, where my package-lock.json and package.json files are located

I created a docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  server:
    container_name: server
    command: 
      - npm
      - run
      - start:dev
    build:
      context: ./server/docker
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    environment:
      PORT: 8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./server:/src/
```

Comment: you may use docker-compose context directive

Comment: @LinPy As I understand it, it uses dockerfiles. How can I do it?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context

Comment: Note, the recommended way to run the code is `CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]`

Answer (score 3):

As explained earlier in comments and previous answers, you cannot copy files which are outside of the build context. So you either need to change the context up the directory path or to move the needed files inside the current context.

Looking at your layout, I would go for the first solution and by default use your base directory as context (once you understand the solution, you can adapt `context` and `dockerfile` to fit your exact needs).

In your `Dockerfile`, change the following lines:

```
COPY ./server/package.json .
COPY ./server/package-lock.json .
```

**Note**: the line `COPY . .` should be removed (or you need to explain a littke better what you actually try to achieve with this)

The build section in your `docker-compose.yml` file should become:

```
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server/docker/Dockerfile
```

The equivalent manual build would be

```
cd /path/to/my-app
docker build -f server/docker/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: I did as you said, and I get an error. `The Compose file is invalid because:
Service server has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.`  in the `copy . .` line I copy all the files

Comment: Sorry I was a little fast on default behaviors. I updated my answer. Context is mandatory

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, because first step of build, is to build the context dirs. You need to change the context.

Straight from [docker docs,](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

> COPY obeys the following rules:
>
> - The  path must be inside the context of the build; 
>     **you cannot COPY ../something /something**, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

Comment: In other words, the Dockerfile is tangential to the app, not "part of it". It goes "next to" the code, not "within the project"

Comment: I created a docker-compose.yml file. The problem is also not solved by m

Comment: @MegaRoks, can you share cocker compose file? Have you added context in that?

Comment: @drd I added the docker-compose.yml file to my question

Comment: any specific reason do you have ` ./.. `? simply  `COPY ../package.json . ` should work